# Can recipients sent to MFMessageComposeViewController be formatted to show name instead of phone number?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4

When sending email, if I set `MFMailComposeViewController` recipients using standard RFC822 recipient format with "name" , `MFMailComposeViewController` will format recipients in the view to show the names with the email addresses hidden. So doing this:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

NSArray *recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           @"\"Bob Paulsen"\ <bob@gmail.com>", 
                           @"\"Sally"\ <sally@gmail.com>", nil
                      ];
[composer setToRecipients:recipients];
```

results in this:
[image]

**My question is:** Is there a magic format I can use to do the same thing in with SMS recipients in MFMessageComposeViewController? I tried using the same format as email but it includes all the text (name and number) in the recipient field. I've tried a few other permutations but so far haven't lucked onto a solution.

Comment: The markup ate part of my first sentence. Was supposed to read: `With "Name" <email>`.

Comment: Okay, looks like it automatically looks up the number you provide in the address book and maps it to contact name. So that works for numbers that are already contacts but still no help if the number is not an existing contact.

Comment: Would love to know the answer to this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do this would be in add a new contact with the recipient number into the user's address book. See the ABAddressBookAddRecord function in the ABAddressBook framework.

However, make sure your users know that this is happening and are OK with it...

Answer (score 1):

I'm using XCode 7.2 (Apple Swift Version 2.1.1) and the following code works for me (without the recipient's email address saved in my address book):

```
let picker = MFMailComposeViewController()    
let recipients = ["\"Name Here\" <email@domain.com>"]
picker.setToRecipients(recipients)
```